# How to combine XML elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<root>
<section>
    <item name="a">
        <uuid>1</uuid>
    </item>
</section>
<section>
    <item name="b">
        <uuid>2</uuid>
    </item>
</section>
</root>
```

I would like to transform it into the following XML:

```
<root>
<section>
    <item name="a">
        <uuid>1</uuid>
    </item>
    <item name="b">
        <uuid>2</uuid>
    </item>
</section>
</root>
```

Thanks in advance.

**Update.**

A slightly different example contains additional elements and attributes.

Input:

```
<root age="1">
<description>some text</description>
<section>
    <item name="a">
        <uuid>1</uuid>
    </item>
</section>
<section>
    <item name="b">
        <uuid>2</uuid>
    </item>
</section>
</root>
```

I would like to transform it into:

```
<root age="1">
<description>some text</description>
<section>
    <item name="a">
        <uuid>1</uuid>
    </item>
    <item name="b">
        <uuid>2</uuid>
    </item>
</section>
</root>
```

Comment: What, exactly, is the question? What have you tried? What goes wrong?

Comment: @Paul Butcher I did not try anything since I'm not familiar with XSLT. The question is simple, how to get the desirable output given provided input

Comment: Try something like Elance, guru.com, vWorker or oDesk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Xsl should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="section item"/>
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <root>
            <section>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="section"/>
            </section>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It gives:

```
<root>
   <section>
      <item name="a">
         <uuid>1</uuid>
      </item>
      <item name="b">
         <uuid>2</uuid>
      </item>
  </section>
</root>
```

**Update:**

For second example you can use following Xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="root item"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="description">
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
       <section>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::section/item"/>
       </section>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="section" />

   <xsl:template match="item">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @Vitaliy it does the trick. However it does not work with my updated example. Could you please provide me with XSLT for the updated example.