# How to combine complex XML elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following input XML:

```
<root age="1">
<description>some text</description>
<section>
    <item name="a">
        <uuid>1</uuid>
    <item>
</section>
<section>
    <item name="b">
        <uuid>2</uuid>
    <item>
</section>
</root>
```

I would like to transform it into the following XML:

```
<root age="1">
<description>some text</description>
<section>
    <item name="a">
        <uuid>1</uuid>
    <item>
    <item name="b">
        <uuid>2</uuid>
    <item>
</section>
</root>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the rule to transform it?  Put all children of all sections into one section?

Comment: @hroptatyr you are right. Put all children of all sections into one section

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007021/how-to-combine-xml-elements-using-xslt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A simpler and shorter solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="section[1]">
   <section>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="../section/node()"/>
   </section>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="section[position() > 1]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root age="1">
    <description>some text</description>
    <section>
        <item name="a">
            <uuid>1</uuid>
        </item>
    </section>
    <section>
        <item name="b">
            <uuid>2</uuid>
        </item>
    </section>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<root age="1">
   <description>some text</description>
   <section>
      <item name="a">
         <uuid>1</uuid>
      </item>
      <item name="b">
         <uuid>2</uuid>
      </item>
   </section>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks @Dimitre Novatchev it works. This is really elegant solution. Could you please provide a short explanation about section[1] and section[position() > 1]

Comment: @SashaKorman: `section[1]` is a match pattern for the first section (of its parent). This is, we want to process and generate a `section` element only once. `section[position() > 1]` is another match pattern that matches all `section` elements, other than what is matched by the former match pattern. The matching template has no body, thus these `section` elements aren't processed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my xslt-1.0 attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name() != 'section']"/>
      <xsl:element name="section">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="section"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```